# Transform double into byteArray in android

Tags: android, parsing, double, arrays, transform

I have a webservice that gets me a list of double's. Now i transform that list in a list of Strings. that i then call in an alert, with an dropdown.
After this i have to take the value from the dropdown, transform it into an byte array.
This is how i tried:

```
float range_m = Float.parseFloat((String) range.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println("range_m: "+ range_m);
            //                int pos = range.getSelectedItemPosition();
            //                String range_m = list.get(pos).replace(".", ",");
            //                configuration.powerLevel = Byte.valueOf(range_m);
            configuration.powerLevel = Byte.valueOf((String) range.getSelectedItem());
```

The problem is that i get the following error:

```
02-11 11:10:11.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14154): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3.0"
02-11 11:10:11.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14154):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:129)
02-11 11:10:11.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14154):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:366)
02-11 11:10:11.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14154):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:357)
02-11 11:10:11.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14154):    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:203)
02-11 11:10:11.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14154):    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:184)
02-11 11:10:11.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14154):    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:245)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a String to a double, then to a numeric primitive data type. Might I suggest doing the conversion one by one?

```
Double dObject = Double.parseDouble(String s);
byte bOutput = dObject.byteValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should do

```
(byte)Double.valueOf (range.getSelectedItem ().toString ())
```

instead of

```
Byte.valueOf((String) range.getSelectedItem())
```